# What is the functional difference between :nohlsearch and :set nohlsearch?

Tags: search, highlight

I noticed that when I use `:nohlsearch` that it does not actually do the same thing as `:set nohlsearch`.

In particular, the `hlsearch` setting is not actually switched off (which is what `:set hlsearch`) accomplishes.

To demonstrate what I mean:

```
:set hlsearch
:nohlsearch
:echo &hlsearch
```

This prints `1` (**hlsearch is still set!**)

```
:set hlsearch
:set nohlsearch
:echo &hlsearch
```

This prints `0` because we switched hlsearch off using the standard way to switch a setting off in vim.

So I'm sort of wondering because there has to be some actual reason for the `:nohlsearch` ex command to exist.

The reason why I care is that I now have a need in my vim scripting to test whether the search highlight is active, and since I was using `:nohlsearch` instead of ":set nohlsearch" in my other scripting, my `&hlsearch` test always returns `1`. So I am wondering what I'm changing by no longer using the `nohlsearch` ex command.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From `:h :nohlsearch`

```
                                                        :noh :nohlsearch
:noh[lsearch]           Stop the highlighting for the 'hlsearch' option.  It
                        is automatically turned back on when using a search
                        command, or setting the 'hlsearch' option.
                        This command doesn't work in an autocommand, because
                        the highlighting state is saved and restored when
                        executing autocommands autocmd-searchpat.
                        Same thing for when invoking a user function.
```

The key point is that it automatically turns the highlighting back on when you start a new search. `:set nohlsearch` actually turns `hlsearch` off, which means the next time you search for something no highlighting occurs.

Example: Assume `hlsearch` is on, If you are currently searching for "hello" in a buffer, all "hello"s will be highlighted . If you use `:nohlsearch` nothing will be highlighted. But if you then search for "world", all "world"s will be highlighted. If you had used `set nohlsearch` instead "world" would not be highlighted.

---

Also note that this command does basically nothing inside a user function. For example,

```
function! NoHlsearch()
    nohlsearch
endfunction
```

has no visible effect when run.

---

To see if hlsearch is actually active you want to check the variable `v:hlsearch`. When `v:hlsearch = 0` highlighting is off, and when `v:hlsearch = 1` highlighting is on. You should probably make sure the `&hlsearch = 1` before checking `v:hlsearch`.

From `:h v:hlsearch`

```
                                        v:hlsearch hlsearch-variable
v:hlsearch      Variable that determines whether search highlighting is on.
                Makes sense only if 'hlsearch' is enabled which requires
                +extra_search. Setting this variable to zero acts the like
                :nohlsearch command, setting it to one acts like
                        let &hlsearch = &hlsearch
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "basically nothing" from inside a function? It does do the standard thing (it temporarily stops highlighting the search until the next time search is invoked).

Comment: I'm also sort of hoping to find a way to access the flag that controls whether the transient `:nohlsearch` is in effect or not... I think in its absence I have to resort to tracking all the `:nohlsearch` calls with a variable.

Comment: @StevenLu see edits.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like the code I have been using hacks around the "basically doing nothing" aspect of it by doing this: `nnoremap <silent> <expr> <boundkey> SearchHighlight()` where `SearchHighlight()` may return a string `":silent nohlsearch\<CR>"`. Also thank you for the `v:hlsearch` tip, just what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

Does your script require that the current state of highlighting be known?

To turn off `hlsearch` for the current search only, I use `Ctrl-l`, with this in my .vimrc:

```
nnoremap <silent> <C-l> :<C-u>nohlsearch<CR><C-l>
```

Search highlighting returns with the next search when using the above command. `Ctrl-l` is convenient because it's normal use is to clear and redraw the screen.

To change the search highlighting state on or off persistently, I use F3 as my toggle:

```
nnoremap <F3> :set hlsearch! hlsearch?<CR>
```