# Search from vim function

Tags: search, highlight

I am trying to use a vim function to search whether `:noh` has been set or not

This is similar to question found [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/3655/how-can-i-make-a-search-in-vimscript-let-n-and-n-look-for-more) except that question does not take `:noh` into account

One way to search from a function is to use `let @/ = 'needle'`

However, after I use `:noh`, this no longer works for any of my functions. I have to call `:set hlsearch` outside of my function for the search to work. Example

```
function! Needle()
  let @/ = 'needle'
endfunction
nnoremap try1 :call Needle()<return>
nnoremap try2 :call Needle()<return>:set hlsearch<return>
```

the mapping "try1" does not work. The mapping "try2" does work.

Question - is there any way to get `:set hlsearch` to work from the function?

**update** - I found that search is indeed being performed, but the highlight is removed. This can be undone by pressing `n` in normal mode. It's still not executed from the funciton, but is closer to the solution I am looking for.

```
function! Needle()
  let @/ = 'needle'
endfunction
nnoremap try1 :call Needle()<return>
nnoremap try2 :call Needle()<return>n
```

"try1" will not work but "try2" will

Comment: Per `:h :noh`, highlighting state is saved and restored when executing user functions. Based on that: not possible.

Comment: @BLayer adding `set hlsearch` and `return ":let v:hlsearch = v:true\<CR>"` worked. Although to be honest, I need to do some research on the `return ":let v:hlsearch = v:true\<CR>"` part because I don't understand what that is doing and I don't like having code I don't understand

Comment: Well, that's not actually doing anything _in_ a user function which would contradict my first comment. :) But, funny thing is I was just about to point you to something that suggests this exact same thing. See last comment under https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/3149/11054

Comment: As for what it is doing, your mapping that calls that function has to have `<expr>`. That says the the right hand side of the mapping will be evaluated as a Vim expression (normally it's interpreted _as is_ ... used literally) and the result will be the actual mapped action. So that makes sense here...the return value of the function (a string) is run as a command and the effect is to do `set hlsearch` outside the function.

Comment: Thanks @BLayer! Also, looks like I was incorrect about `set hlsearch` and `return ":let v:hlsearch = v:true\<CR>"`, it is still not working after I do `:noh`... I'm not sure how it was working the first time, but i had probably pressed `:set hls` and forgot. For now I may have to accept this as something vim can't do... but simply add `n` to a mapping is easy so I guess that's good enough.

Comment: No problem. Have your  function end with `return "set hlsearch"` and for your mapping use something like `:nnoremap <silent> <expr> <boundkey> "Needle()"`. Replace `<boundkey>` with whatever key(s) you want, obviously. I just tried it and it worked. (The comment I pointed you to is missing the quotes around the function name.)

Comment: Hmmm interesting! It is performing a search which is something I have not gotten vim to do yet. But for me, it is just performing the previous search, rather than the search defined in the `needle()` function. For example, if I do `/some_search` and the press the boundkeys for the mapping, the map calls `needle()` but "some_search" is highlighted instead of "needle". Are you able to get it to search for the text inside the method? Or was it repeating the previous search for you?

Comment: Not sure. I was just looking at the return value part. If that's not working, well, it was kind of a hack to begin with. :P Can you use a user command instead of a function. :)

Comment: Oh, I'll have to give that a try! Thanks @BLayer!!

Answer (score 2):

It is a little tricky but this can be done. First you have to search using `let @/ = 'needle'`. This initiates the search. However, none of the highlights appear. To get the highlights, you simply need to go to the "next" instance with `:normal! n`, which will highlight all instances and move the cursor to the next instance. Final solution:

```
function! Needle()
  let @/ = 'needle'
  :normal! n
endfunction

nnoremap ,needle :call Needle()<return>
```

Thanks B Layer and Ben Knoble for the help!

Comment: Does `:normal! n` work in the function?

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks @D.BenKnoble

Answer (score 0):

to check the state of `:noh` its `hlsearch` or `nohlsearch`, you can check it one of these ways:

```
:set hlsearch?
```

or

```
:set nohlsearch?
```

Comment: Once again, this has nothing to do with the question being asked, which is not about checking the value of the option. We appreciate your enthusiasm for answering and contributing, and we ask that you read the question carefully and focus your answer to it.